# Should Image.fromarray(pixels) and np.array(img) leave the data unchanged?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to generate PNGs using the Image.fromarray() function from PIL but not getting the expected images.

```
arr=np.random.randint(0,256,5*5)
arr.resize((5,5))
print arr
```

gives

```
[[255 217 249 221  88]
 [ 28 207  85 219  85]
 [ 90 145 155 152  98]
 [196 121 228 101  92]
 [ 50 159  66 130   8]]
```

then

```
img=Image.fromarray(arr,'L')
new_arr=np.array(img)
```

I would expect new_arr to be the same as arr but

```
print new_arr
[[122   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0  61   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0 168   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0 221]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `np.random.randint()` returns signed int, while the `'L'` option to `Image.fromarray()` tells it to interpret the array as 8-bit **unsigned** int ([PIL modes](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes)). If you explicitly cast it to `uint8` it works:

```
arr=np.random.randint(0,256,5*5)
arr.resize((5,5))
print arr
```

output:

```
[[255 217 249 221  88]
 [ 28 207  85 219  85]
 [ 90 145 155 152  98]
 [196 121 228 101  92]
 [ 50 159  66 130   8]]
```

then

```
img=Image.fromarray(arr.astype('uint8'),'L')  # cast to uint8
new_arr=np.array(img)
print new_arr
```

output:

```
[[255 217 249 221  88]
 [ 28 207  85 219  85]
 [ 90 145 155 152  98]
 [196 121 228 101  92]
 [ 50 159  66 130   8]]
```